# Problems with prepared statements for a select query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, mariadb, sql-injection

i have an application running on php/mysql, and it recently entered into production stage, so i need to secure the whole infrastructure beginning with some protection against SQL injection.
One of the things i'm doing is converting all the input from users into prepared statement instead of direct query.
That worked perfectly until i begin to work on the login page.
The following code is (mysql query only)

1. the (UNSECURE) but functioning code i'm using today
2. the CODE to replace it that isn't working.

For this example, user_list will be my table on the database and usr, pswHash the
fields to check for the login. id will be the auto-incrementing row identifier.

1)

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE usr = $user AND pswHash = $passHash";
```

2)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE usr=? AND pswHash=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $passHash);
```

The second code fragment is non working, since the output from the query will be null in any case, either with correct or wrong usr/pass combinations.

If this is not enough i can post the whole snippets, but i guess this problem has something to do with the SQL query.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks fine to me. Have you checked for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: _Side note:_ How are you hashing the passwords? You should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: You are missing `$stmt->execute();` and `$stmt->fetch();`

Comment: BTW, that's not the proper way to use passwords in PHP, even that passwords are managed by an external program (e.g: Active Directory)

Comment: 'it recently entered into production stage' - so now you want to make it secure?!

Comment: Apply Bcrypt Password Encoding. You are securing it in production stage?

Comment: I know this is not the perfect practice, but it's my first application and it has a small user base (~10 users).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would code it:

```
function password_matches($mysqli, $user, $pass) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pswHash FROM user_list WHERE usr=?");
    // always check for errors after prepare()
    if (!$stmt) {
      error_log($mysqli->error);
      return false;
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);

    $ok = $stmt->execute();
    // always check for errors after execute()
    if (!$ok) {
      error_log($mysqli->error);
      return false;
    }

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if (password_verify($pass, $row['pswHash'])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    // if the result set had zero matches for $user,
    // or if there were any matches for $user, but none of them
    // had a password hash matching the input
    return false;
}
```

This is assuming you used [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create the password hash before you inserted it to the database.

Always check both `prepare()` or `execute()` to see if it return **false**. If they do, then log `$mysqli->error`, and keep watching your http server error log. This is general advice while you develop SQL queries. If you write the wrong SQL syntax, or you don't have the right SQL privileges, or something else happens, you want to know.